# Show that $C- (A ∪ B) = (C - A)\cap (C - B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> For sets $A, B, C$: $$C- (A ∪ B) = (C - A)\cap (C - B).$$

I'm not sure how to formulate a correct proof for this statement. I assume that any element $x$ in set $C$ can't be in either $A$ or $B$, however I'm wrong about these things around 90% of the time.

Comment: Use De Morgan's laws: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove a set equality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006136/how-to-prove-a-set-equality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  $X$ be a set, $A,B,C$ be subsets of $X$.

$C-(A \cup B) = C \cap (A \cup B)^c = $

$C \cap (A^c\cap B^c) =$

$ (C\cap A^c)\cap (C \cap B^c)=$

$(C-A)\cap (C-B)$.

Used:

de Morgan: $(A\cup B)^c= A^c \cap B^c$;

$C-D= C \cap D^c$, where $D=A,B$.

Comment: What do you mean with universal set? Surely, something like $X\supseteq A\cup B\cup C$ where $X$ really is a set, however I really dislike that terminology as *universal set* comes with this intuitive connection to the set of all sets(also called the universal set sometimes) with is (besides being not a set but a class) a topic to be carefully dealt with (like sethood in general).

Comment: Ok, not universal .Superset.

Comment: I mean, your line of reasoning is a very nice way to show the equality just through set algebra (+1), this phrase just makes me nervous whenever I read it.

Comment: zzuussee.No worry . Thank you for your kind words .Sometimes   the term universal set is used. But I agree, no need to use a terminology which is ambigous, one can do without .Greetings.

Comment: This of course assumes that you have already proved the relations with complement. And the complement is probably defined via set difference …

Comment: @zzuussee: Note that only certain foundational systems have a problem with the universal set. Others do not, so it could be misleading to say that the universal set is actually not a set but a class. And in ZFC one has to go a convoluted route, namely to let $X = \bigcup \{\bigcup \{A,B\},C\}$, which is just an artifact of ZFC.

Answer (score 2):

You could approach this via double inclusion, i.e. showing that

$$C-(A\cup B)\subseteq(C-A)\cap (C-B)\text{ and }(C-A)\cap (C-B)\subseteq C-(A\cup B)$$

---

I'll just show the former one and leave the rest to you:

Let $x\in C-(A\cup B)$, i.e. $x\in C$ and $x\not\in(A\cup B)$, i.e. $x\not\in A$ and $x\not\in B$. Thus, by the first, $x\in C-A$, by the second, $x\in C-B$. Thus $x\in (C-A)\cap (C-B)$

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this cleared it right up

Comment: @PeterCelinski You're very welcome.