# Prove or disprove C∖(A∪B)=(C∖A)∩(C∖B)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

So I've tried a bunch of sets and I believe the statement to be true. However I am not quite sure how to formulate a correct proof. I know so far that for an element x in set $C$, it cannot be in set $A$ or $B$. And on the right side, we are taking the union of the sets where for an element $x$, $C\setminus A$ and $C\setminus B$ is $x$ that is in $C$ but not $A$ and $B$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399799/prove-that-a-b-cap-a-c-a-cap-b-cup-cc-for-any-three-sets-a-b-c

Answer (score 1):

Since in general $X \setminus Y = X \cap Y'$

You get:

$C\setminus (A \cup B) = C \cap (A \cup B)' = C \cap A' \cap B' = C \cap A ' \cap C \cap B' = (C \setminus A) \cap (C \setminus B)$

Answer (score 1):

Recall for sets $X$ and $Y$, $X \setminus Y$ is the set of elements of $X$ which aren't elements of $Y$.

We want to show that elements of $C \setminus (A \cup B)$ are elements of $(C \setminus A) \cap (C \setminus B)$ and vice versa.

Suppose that $x \in C \setminus (A \cup B)$ then $x \in C$ and $x \not \in A \cup B$ so $x$ is in neither $A$ or $B$. Hence $x \in C \setminus A$ and $x \in C \setminus B$ so $x \in (C \setminus A) \cap (C \setminus B)$. This means $C \setminus (A \cup B) \subseteq (C \setminus A) \cap (C \setminus B)$.

Showing the reverse inclusion to complete the proof follows in a similar manner.